# Click event to call a js file, then load contents into div

Tags: javascript, html, src

I would like to be able to click on the Orange text to be able to call the orange.js file, then load the .js file into the myTableResult div.  I would like the name of the .js file to be inside the onclick event.  Can somebody help me with that?

```
<a onclick="getScript('Orange.js');"/>Orange</a>

<div id="myTableResult">


</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myapp/htmlCode"></script>
```

Comment: Do you want to evaluate the JS file or just show its contents?

Comment: Hi, smallpepperz, Just show its contents.  The JS files are just tables I wish to load in the divs

Comment: "The JS files are just tables" no they aren't. Tables don't exist in JS. You also have an invalid src for that script tag that mentions "htmlCode". What are you trying to load? HTML or JS?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jquery, you can use:

```
$.getScript( "ajax/test.js", ()=>{
// after load
}
});
```

to get the script and execute whatever command you want in the after load section (call functions, .etc).

if you are using vanilla javascript, then you need to first add your script to document body and then call any function you want like this:

```
    function getScript(srcFile){
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = srcFile;
        document.head.appendChild(script);
    }
```

And to pass result to your element you need to do

jquery:

```
$('#myTableResult').html(your_html_goes_here)
```

vanilla js:

document.getElementById("myTableResult").innerHTML="your_html_goes_here"

Comment: Thanks Hamed.  I am using vanilla javascript.  I would like to have the file path 'Orange.js' in the click event, not in the script.  When the page loads, I am loading multiple onclick events.  My goal is to have a universal script, where I am only updating the onclick events.

Comment: your welcome, no problem. you need to call this function inside your onclick event. that way you can get the script and then execute what ever you want. in your case you function myClickFunc(){ getScript("Orange.js"); /*resetOfMyCode*/ }

Answer (score 0):

You want to append HTML to the DOM so given a file named `Orange.html` containing the following HTML:

Orange.html

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Sweetness</th>
        <th>Size</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Valencia</td>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>8</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jaffa</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>7</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

index.html

```html
<a href="#" 
   class="load-table-link" 
   data-file="./Orange.html" 
   data-destination="myTableResult">Orange
</a>
<div id="myTableResult"></div>
```

The following code will allow you to append the table to the DOM using fetch:

```js
// Select all load-table-link a tags
const loadLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.load-table-link');
// Loop through them and add click events
if(loadLinks.length){
    for(const link of loadLinks){
        link.addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
            e.preventDefault();
            // Get filename from data-file attribute
            const file = e.target.dataset.file;
            // Get target div from data-destination attribute
            const destination = e.target.dataset.destination;
            addFileToDestination(file, destination);
        })
    }
}
const addFileToDestination = (file, destination) =>{
    fetch(file).then(response => {
        return response.text();
    }).then(data => {
        const section = document.createElement('section');
        section.innerHTML = data;
        document.querySelector(`#${destination}`).appendChild(section)
    });
}
```

I have made the code extensible so for each `<a href="#" class="load-table-link">` you just need to add the name of the file containing your html tables in the `data-file` attribute and the target `div` id in the `data-destination` attribute.

Comment: This is probably the answer to the actual question the OP has, but it doesn't actually answer the question they asked....

Comment: @JaredSmith yes I am trying to guide OP into using .html files to hold his tables.

Comment: @jQueeny Thanks for guiding me in the right direction. Yes, you are correct.  It sounds like loading an HTML file is the better approach.  I tried your code and got an error - "origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, https, edge."

Comment: Are your files in the same root directory, i.e. is Orange.html in the same directory as index.html?

Comment: That sounds like a fetch error when you are trying to run the page using `file://` instead of serving it over localhost or from public dns/ip.

Comment: @JQuenny  Yes, the files are in the same root directory and yes the page is using file://  Is there anyway around this?

Comment: So you need to set up a server with Node/Express or Apache etc. If you can't then your IDE can typically serve the files over a local server. VS Code Live Server for example. Using file protocol is fine for checking html/css etc but if you want make network requests you need a server.

Comment: @RickD good advice you will probably ignore: stop what you are doing. Go read/watch a tutorial on beginning web development. Work your way through it. Don't skip steps even if they don't make sense to you now. Then do another 1 or 2. Every piece of documentation you read, everyone you interact with here on SO or on Reddit, is going to assume you have already done at least this much. You are going to waste a lot of time (your own and other people's) trying to freestyle your way through this.

Answer (score -2):

maybe you need to especify a little bit more your question, but here is an example of html and js injection.

First i prefer to use button instend of a just because the side effects of a tag element here is the code:

```
<button type="button" onclick="getScript('orange')">Orange</button>

<div id="myTableResult"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    const getScript = (fileName) => {
        const scriptElement = document.createElement("script");
        scriptElement.type = "text/javascript";
        scriptElement.src = `./js/${fileName}.js`;
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(scriptElement);
    }
</script>
```

Then on my "orange.js" file i do something like this:

```
const dummyHeaders = [
    'ID',
    'Name',
    'Status'
];

const dummyData = [
    {id: 0, name: 'orange', status: true},
    {id: 1, name: 'apple', status: true},
    {id: 2, name: 'strawberry', status: true},
];

const init = () => {
    // get div reference
    const element = document.getElementById('myTableResult');

    // create table and added to dom
    const table = document.createElement('table');
    element.appendChild(table);

    // create table headers and added to dom
    const thead = document.createElement('thead');
    table.appendChild(thead);

    const trHeads = document.createElement('tr');
    thead.appendChild(trHeads);

    for(let dataHeads of dummyHeaders) {

        // create new th element for each header setted
        const th = document.createElement('th');
        th.textContent = dataHeads;
        trHeads.appendChild(th);
    }

    
    // table body
    const tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
    table.appendChild(tbody);

    for(let data of dummyData) {

        // create new row for each object in array and added to the dom
        const trBody = document.createElement('tr');
        tbody.appendChild(trBody);

        // get each property of the element iterated
        const dataTd = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(data);
        for(let tdInfo of dataTd) {
            // create a new td element for each property on the object
            const td = document.createElement('td');
            td.textContent = data[tdInfo];
            trBody.appendChild(td);
        }
        
    }


}

init();
```

Hope this could help you :).

Comment: Thanks @RobyOneG that worked.  On the Orange.js file, is there a way to incorporate what I already have currently in my JS files?  Here is a sample of my JS files that are all tables. `function GetOrange() {
var data = '<table id="TableResult1"> \
<tr class="Color"> \
<tr><td>Red</td> \
<td>Blue</td> \
<td>White</td></tr> \
</table> '
document.getElementById('myTableResult').innerHTML =data;
}`

Comment: i recomend you to create the elements to have a better customization at a long term project than using strings and added to dom using innterHTML, maybe could be a little bit easy but its way to dirty, i mean, if you need to make some changes on the table would be a hell when you have like a lot of them

Comment: FYI: `type="text/javascript"` has not been needed for several years now as `text/javascript` is the default value for the `type` attribute on a `script` element. Also, [don't use `getElementsByTagName()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54952088/how-to-modify-style-to-html-elements-styled-externally-with-css-using-js/54952474#54952474). Instead of `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]`, just use `document.body`.